# KendoDraggable - Really Drag and Drop function

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, kendo-ui

I would like to ask for help with my D&D function...

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5kJf/5/

Function D&D is implemented but I can't fix bug when you drop object to his original target. If you do it, object will split in two.

Please help me.
-David

Answer (score 1):

I found issue in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RichardAD/K27fu/

Only one thing what was needed is change this line:

```
this.element.html(this.element.html() + e.draggable.element[0].outerHTML);
```

By this:

```
this.element.append(e.draggable.currentTarget);
```

Hopes that helps other...

Best regards,
-David